# Appending to a list from a for loop (to read a text file)

Tags: python, string, list, append, slice

How do I append to an undetermined list from a for loop?
The purpose is to first slice each line by '-'. Then I would like to append these slices to an array without a determined size. I have the following code, and am loosing hair because of how simple this seems!

Each line in the text file looks like the following: 
2014-06-13,42.7,-73.8,27

program so far:

```
f = open('Lightning.txt')

lightning =list()

for templine in f:

    if not templine.startswith('2014'): continue

    templine = templine.rstrip('-')

    line = templine.split()

    print line[2]
```

Thank you community,

Comment: Can u show us the exact output that you would like to get with `2014-06-13,42.7,-73.8,27` input?

Comment: I would like to get out: (2014-04-10 :   27 lightning strikes were recorded.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that if you want to get list of formated strings.

```
f = open('Lightning.txt')
lightning =list()
for templine in f:
    if not templine.startswith('2014'): continue
    # We are splitting the line by ',' to get [2014-06-13, 42.7,-73.8, 27]
    templine = templine.split(',')
    # After splitting is done, we know that at the 1st place is the date, 
    # and at the last one is the number of video recordings.

    #Here we asign the first item to "data" and the last one to "num_of_strikes"
    date, num_of_strikes = templine[0], templine[-1]
    # After that is done, we create the output string with placeholders 
    # {data} and {num} waiting for data to be passed
    output = '{date} : {num} lightning strikes were recorded.'
    # Here we are appending the formated string, passing our data to placeholders
    # And yes, they work like a dictionary, so u can write (key = value)
    lightning.append(output.format(date= date, num= num_of_strikes))
```

Comment: date, num_of_strikes = templine[0], templine[-1]
    output = '{date} : {num} lightning strikes were recorded.'
    lightning.append(output.format(date= date, num= num_of_strikes))

Comment: could you please describe this process? I would greatly appreciate this!

Comment: Done. Read the comments, I'm hope it helped.

Comment: Such a life saver, I'll have to digest it but I'll get it. Thank you so much Nf4r!

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal job for the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) lib:

```
import csv

with open('Lightning.txt') as f:
    data = []
    # unpack the elements from each line/row
    for dte, _, _, i in csv.reader(f):
        # if the date starts with 2014, add the date string and the last element i
        if dte.startswith('2014'):
            data.append((dte, i))
```

Which can all be done using a list comp:

```
import csv

with open('Lightning.txt') as f:
    data = [(dte, i) for dte, _, _, i in csv.reader(f) if dte.startswith('2014')]
```